# Regarding ELK-Logstash keyword filter passing to zabbix trapper

Tags: logstash, zabbix

Regarding ELK-Logstash keyword filter passing to zabbix trapper, how can i configure the logstash filter to send a particular message to zabbix trapper according to the key word in each received message line?
i've completely configured zabbix-server trapper, and message zabbix-sender works fine on the client server, but seems the filter configuration is a bit difficult to me at the moment.
My logstash is based on 6.4 and Zabbix server is based on 3.4, the current logstash filter configuration is like below:

```
filter {
  if [prospector][type] == "log" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the filter creating the fields you're expecting?  Do you have an output{} stanza?

Comment: yes, the existed grok filter works fine for regular message delivery; but if i want to make a particular filter for key words like 'ERROR' to send a message to output of zabbix-server via zabbix-trapper interface, what should i do? i've done some research myself and several hrs tries, but unfortunately not working. any advice is really appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the existed grok filter works fine for regular message delivery; but if i want to make a particular filter for key words like 'ERROR' to send a message to output of zabbix-server via zabbix-trapper interface, what should i do? i've done some research myself and several hrs tries, but unfortunately not working.  any advice is really appreciated. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a conditional output, you can do it like this:

```
output {
    if [message] =~ /eek/ {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

This config is testing the `message` field to see if it contains `eek`.

Assuming the [zabbix output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-zabbix.html) does what you want, you could use a similar structure to route data to the zabbix.